# How can I reproduce linux's `column -t` command equivalent in windows?

Tags: linux, windows, batch-file

What is the equivalent command for [Linux's column command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/column) in windows?
How can I reproduce `column -t` in windows?
I cant find anything related on windows batch file commands list.

any help is greatly appreciated.

### UPDATE:

Actually I'm trying to port the following portion from a script([which can be found here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382389/conversion-from-unix-bash-script-to-windows-batch-scrip)) to its windows counter part:

```
paste aux0.txt aux3.txt aux1.txt aux2.txt | column -t >> $LOG.train
```

Comment: Will this be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441827/windows-command-for-cutting-columns-from-a-text

Comment: @manjesh23: Thanks, I have no idea if our problem is the same!, I edited my question in a hope it provide more information.

Comment: Is there any reason against using PowerShell? While there is weeping and gnashing of teeth in complex tasks in bat and cmd, it can be a piece of cake in ps. column -t is there in Format-Table (ft) of PS.  But if you insist, you can get gawk from here: http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ and once you have it, you're free to go.

Comment: @GombaiSandor: well, I dont know power shell and if its available in all versions of windows. and if running and executing it is any different than the batch files. 
If it gets the job done why not.?

Comment: Just have a look at its wiki page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell). I heard the rumour of bash on W10 but heard also that it would not be able to interact with windowed apps. PS defeats bash in that battlefield in addition to that it can really work as a usual (well, a bit unusual) script language. CMD has been always a bad joke of "let's make the easy tasks hard to do and even harder to maintain". So I would go (have) for PS if I had to work with Win's. The sooner the better.

Comment: @user556625 `Format-Table` **cannot** work as a replacement to `column -t` the former can only work on Powershell structured output and **not** free text output where we only look at a separator. So your suggestion is pointless here.